# ASP.Net MVC3 Razor Jqgrid not rendering the View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

In my project i have to implement Datagrid View.After several research i found that Jqgrid is more flexible in custom Gird view in asp.net mvc3 razor.
So by reading the tutorial [Using jQuery Grid With ASP.NET MVC][1] i have created a controller and a view .But now its not rendering the view page.When i click the link from index page its just showing that error 404.Page not found.

**My Controller Code**

```
      [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ViewEmployeeData()
        {
            return View();
        }
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewEmployeeData(string Eord, string Empid, int page,  int rows)
        {

            ElixirERPContext empdata = new ElixirERPContext();
            var query = from emp in empdata.EmpData
                        select emp;
            var count = query.Count();
            var resultquery = new
            {
                tottal = 1,
                page = page,
                records = count,
                rows = query.Select(x => new { x.EmpId, x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.LastName, x.Address, x.DateOfJoining, x.Department, x.Position }).ToList()
                     .Select(x => new { id = x.EmpId,Date=x.DateOfJoining, cell = new string[] { x.EmpId.ToString(), x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.LastName, x.Address, x.DateOfJoining.ToString(), x.Department, x.Position } }).ToArray(),
            };
            return Json(resultquery, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            //return View();
        }
  [1]: htt
```

p://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx/

**View Page**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewEmployeeData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}

  @* Script For Jqgrid*@
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/ViewEmployeeData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['EmpId', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'Address', 'DateOfJoining', 'Department', 'Position'],
        colModel: [
      { name: 'EmpId', index: 'EmpId', width: 40, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 40, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
      { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
      { name: 'DateOfJoining', index: 'DateOfJoining', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
      { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
      { name: 'Position', index: 'Position', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        width: 660,
        height: 'auto',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'EmpId',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Employee Information'
    });
}); 
</script>

<h2>ViewEmployeeData</h2>
<table id="list" ></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

**Index Page**

```
 <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-table-2"></i>Employee Management</a>
                        <ul>
                         <li><a href="@Url.Action("EmployeeRegistration", "Home")"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>Employee registration</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("ViewEmployeeData", "Home")""><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>View/Edit Employee Details</a></li>

                        </ul>
```

Comment: perphaps you need HttpGet not HttpPost attribute to specify. Or another ActionResult with HttpGet to render this grid...

Comment: @xurca When i am using Httpget also the same result is happening..no change. i have tried both .

Comment: @xurca..hello i have edited the code .Now the page is rendering without grid.Just a blank page

Comment: well then check your browser if it throws some js exceptions and check your js code i think its incorrect

Comment: @xurca..When i debug the code its not entering into the script section.Is there any error in my controller code.

Comment: in jqGrid block you have extra bracets ] this one. check them and delete

Comment: Okay I got it..can u post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jqGrid block you have extra bracets. check them and delete

```
colModel: [
      { name: 'EmpId', index: 'EmpId', width: 40, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 40, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 200, align: 'left'}  ],
      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 200, align: 'left'}  ],
      { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 200, align: 'left'}  ],
      { name: 'DateOfJoining', index: 'DateOfJoining', width: 200, align: 'left'}  ],
      { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 200, align: 'left'}  ],
      { name: 'Position', index: 'Position', width: 200, align: 'left'}]
```